# Class lookup value to return correct match

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am trying to get my code to work, where I have the different #Enigma Rotors and reflectors defined however would like to be able to look from left to right and right to left for a specific character entered. Then returning the same alphabetical character in the position of the selected rotor.

In the code below you will see I added the different rotors and reflectors in the bottom section. The "rotor_from_name" is to select the specific rotor and the other functions should search for the letter and return the ALPHABETIC letter. The rotor variable has the selector however I am not sure how I can get this selector to return the full 26 letters linked to this?

```
import string
# Getting the uppercase alphabet
ALPHABET = string.ascii_uppercase

class Rotor:
    TURN_FREQUENCY = len(ALPHABET)

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def encode_right_to_left(self, x):
        self.alphabet = ALPHABET
        j = rotor.find(x)
        return j

    def encode_left_to_right(self, x):
        self.alphabet = ALPHABET
        j = self.alphabet.rfind(x)
        return j
    
    @classmethod
    def rotor_from_name(self, y):
        self.y = y
        return y

if __name__=='__main__':
    instance = Rotor()
    #Enigma Rotors and reflectors
    Beta = "LEYJVCNIXWPBQMDRTAKZGFUHOS"
    Gamma = "FSOKANUERHMBTIYCWLQPZXVGJD"
    I = "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ"
    II = "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE"
    III = "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO"
    IV = "ESOVPZJAYQUIRHXLNFTGKDCMWB"
    V = "VZBRGITYUPSDNHLXAWMJQOFECK"
```

The expected results are the following:

```
rotor = rotor_from_name("I")
assert(rotor.encode_right_to_left("A") == "E")
assert(rotor.encode_left_to_right("A") == "U")
```

Thank you for any support and/or guidance on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed some bugs

- `TURN_FREQUENCY` never used, you should remove it.
- If you dont need `__init__`, just remove it, no need to add a `__init__` only have one line `pass`.
- You need set a proper name to the variable `self.y`, such as `self.rotor`.`self.y` is really confusing.
- You create a `instance` to `Rotor`, then you need use it, not to use the lowercase `rotor`, which is never defined.
- When you need to assign the rotor to the instance, you need assign the varible, not a stirng like `"I"`
- I think you may need a IDE to debug your code, such as VSCode, PyCharm.

code:

```
import string

class Rotor:
    
    def encode_right_to_left(self, x):
        return self.rotor[ALPHABET.index(x)]

    def encode_left_to_right(self, x):
        return ALPHABET[self.rotor.index(x)]
    
    def rotor_from_name(self, rotor):
        self.rotor = rotor

ALPHABET = string.ascii_uppercase
instance = Rotor()
Beta = "LEYJVCNIXWPBQMDRTAKZGFUHOS"
Gamma = "FSOKANUERHMBTIYCWLQPZXVGJD"
I = "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ"
II = "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE"
III = "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO"
IV = "ESOVPZJAYQUIRHXLNFTGKDCMWB"
V = "VZBRGITYUPSDNHLXAWMJQOFECK"
instance.rotor_from_name(I)
print(instance.encode_right_to_left("A"))
assert(instance.encode_right_to_left("A") == "E")
print(instance.encode_left_to_right("A"))
assert(instance.encode_left_to_right("A") == "U")

instance.rotor_from_name(Beta)
print(instance.encode_right_to_left("A"))
assert(instance.encode_right_to_left("A") == "L")
print(instance.encode_left_to_right("A"))
assert(instance.encode_left_to_right("A") == "R")
```

result:

```
E
U

L
R
```

**EDIT:** If you want to use varibale name to select router, you can use `loacls()`

code:

```
instance.rotor_from_name(locals()["I"])
print(instance.encode_right_to_left("A"))
assert(instance.encode_right_to_left("A") == "E")
print(instance.encode_left_to_right("A"))
assert(instance.encode_left_to_right("A") == "U")

instance.rotor_from_name(locals()["Beta"])
print(instance.encode_right_to_left("A"))
assert(instance.encode_right_to_left("A") == "L")
print(instance.encode_left_to_right("A"))
assert(instance.encode_left_to_right("A") == "R")
```

result:

```
E
U

L
R
```

Or, you can write a dict to translate name key to chart value.
code:

```
def rotor_from_name(name):
    rotor_dic = {
    "Beta" : "LEYJVCNIXWPBQMDRTAKZGFUHOS",
    "Gamma" : "FSOKANUERHMBTIYCWLQPZXVGJD",
    "I" : "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ",
    "II" : "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE",
    "III" : "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO",
    "IV" : "ESOVPZJAYQUIRHXLNFTGKDCMWB",
    "V" : "VZBRGITYUPSDNHLXAWMJQOFECK"}
    return rotor_dic[name]

ALPHABET = string.ascii_uppercase
instance = Rotor()

rotor = rotor_from_name("I")
instance.rotor_from_name(rotor)
print(instance.encode_right_to_left("A"))
assert(instance.encode_right_to_left("A") == "E")
print(instance.encode_left_to_right("A"))
assert(instance.encode_left_to_right("A") == "U")

rotor = rotor_from_name("Beta")
instance.rotor_from_name(rotor)
print(instance.encode_right_to_left("A"))
assert(instance.encode_right_to_left("A") == "L")
print(instance.encode_left_to_right("A"))
assert(instance.encode_left_to_right("A") == "R")
```

result:

```
E
U

L
R
```

Comment: Hi leaf_yakitori, thank you very much for the feedback and the elaborations on the code, it is appreciated. How will I be able to make use of the "rotor = rotor_from_name("I")" to select the router. as the current proposal uses the instance variable, which I would not like to use for setting the rotor selection?

Comment: Thank you leaf_yakitori, it is truly appreciated, it is exactly what I was looking for